# How to get the version of my nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried using `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` but it says the file does not exist.

Is there any alternative way to do that?

I tried to look manually for that file, but I couldn't find it. I also searched for
it and still could not find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried the command you have post with `sudo` ?

Comment: @HananN. That file is world-readable on my system, and you wouldn't get a "file does not exist" error if it wasn't

Comment: @Rev3rse: are you sure the nvidia module is loaded? Does it appear in  `lsmod`? `dmesg|grep -i nvidia`?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774651/switching-between-nvdia-driver-versions-on-16-04, https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 23):

Try to run the `nvidia-smi` command. It will give you information about your driver version, the cards you have in your system, etc. The advantage is that you do not need a GUI, and it is an altervative to `modinfo nvidia`.

Comment: Is this actually a solution or a recommendation for the next step in troubleshooting? If the latter, it should be a comment.

Comment: It is nvidia's own management program, which should answer the original question.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way to isolate the NVidia Driver Version number *alone* is to run the following:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader
```

On my system this produces the following result:

```
andrew@ilium~$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader
510.60.02
andrew@ilium~$
```

Comment: That is assuming the `nvidia` driver is loaded, which might not be the case if the system is using a Bumblebee-type solution to power down the discrete GPU to save power... which woukd have been the way to do it back in 2011 when the question was written.

Answer (score 10):

Ok.. first of all, what is this video card and what kernel module is loaded:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV41 [GeForce 6800 GS] (rev a2)
  Kernel driver in use: nvidia
  Kernel modules: nvidia, nouveau, nvidiafb
$ _
```

So I do have nVidia graphics card with loaded kernel module - "nvidia".
Let's see more about this driver, but search for the "version":

```
$ modinfo nvidia | grep version
```

Although you could just read a full output if ".. | grep version" returns no result:

```
$ modinfo nvidia
```

Comment: I get no results on my nvidia system

Comment: Because "could not find module"? Or "| grep version" returned nothing?

Comment: Grep returned nothing; [this is the output of `modinfo nvidia` on my system](http://sprunge.us/DaQH)

Answer (score 4):

try `nvidia-settings` and on the Gui that open you should see the version number.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use nvidia-settings from command line:

> $ nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion
>
> Attribute 'NvidiaDriverVersion' (neptune:0.0): 304.117

Use *all* to get the whole attribute list (verbose!)

> $ nvidia-settings -q all

Comment: Yours worked for Pop-OS. Thanks